# Mousehover not working in google chrome 45 css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I want to display a sub `ul` with class `submenu` when hovered on `li`. For that I have written the below CSS code. The below code is working in all the browsers except in Google Chrome 45.

```
    nav .sub-menu li:hover .sub-menu{ display:block;}
```

My HTML code is

```
    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-49" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-4 current_page_item menu-item-49"><a href="http://natcopharma.co.in/">Home</a></li>

   <li id="menu-item-693" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-693"><a href="#">Products</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li id="menu-item-758" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-758"><a href="#">Domestic Formulations</a>
       <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-101" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-101"><a href="http://natcopharma.co.in/products/domestic-formulations/oncology-hematology/">Oncology – Hematology</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-100" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-100"><a href="http://natcopharma.co.in/products/domestic-formulations/oncology-solid-tumors/">Oncology – Solid Tumors</a></li>
         <li id="menu-item-99" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-99"><a href="http://natcopharma.co.in/products/domestic-formulations/speciality-pharma/">Speciality Pharma</a></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
    <li id="menu-item-105" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-105"><a href="http://natcopharma.co.in/products/international-formulations/">International Formulations</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li id="menu-item-694" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-694"><a href="#">Innovation</a>
 <ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-322" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-322"><a href="http://natcopharma.co.in/innovation/analytical/">Analytical</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-323" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-323"><a href="http://natcopharma.co.in/innovation/generic-research/">Generic Research</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-324" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-324"><a href="http://natcopharma.co.in/innovation/intellectual-property/">Intellectual Property</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-325" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-325"><a href="http://natcopharma.co.in/innovation/new-drug-discovery/">New Drug Discovery</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-326" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-326"><a href="http://natcopharma.co.in/innovation/opportunities/">Opportunities</a></li>
  </ul>
   </li>
   <li id="menu-item-347" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-347"><a href="http://natcopharma.co.in/global/">Global</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ubpcjr97/

Comment: Add a FIDDLE for the query

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ubpcjr97/

Comment: It is working for Chrome version**45.0.2454.85 m** for windows.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it works. I've tested it right now in Chrome 45.

Answer (score 0):

It's working in my browser but you can also try this :

```
nav .sub-menu li:hover > .sub-menu{ display:block;}
```